# BlackBerry: How to get call log/delete a call log entry

Tags: blackberry, calllog

In BlackBerry platform, I would like to know if it is possible / how to do the following:

1. Retrieve the call log (I am particularly interested in the incomming call record);
2. Delete a specific call log;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To retrieve the phone logs take a look at [PhoneCallLog class](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/phone/phonelogs/PhoneCallLog.html).

Even [in the most recent version](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/phone/phonelogs/PhoneCallLog.html) of BlackBerry RIM SDK there is no functionality to delete a call log record.

Answer (score 0):

PhoneLogs class is the one that should be used. Take a look at PhoneLogs.deleteCall() method.